# Prevent value changes to trigger in autocomplete setValue

Tags: angular

I have created an autocomplete and an options component, when we type search phrase in input field, I call the web service and get the data and then show the list in option component, but when I select an option from that list and set the value to the input field then the web service alls again fires. How can I prevent this? Example is how material design autocomplete works, I want similar functionality while selecting something from the options list. Thank you.

```html
<app-rx-search-field>
          <input id="rx-search-field" type="search" class="form-control __search_field" name="search" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" [formControl]="providerSchoolSearchCtrl" formControlName="school" />
          <app-rx-options [optionsList]="suggestedSchoolsList$ | async" [key]="'school.name'" (optionSelected)="onOptionSelected($event)"></app-rx-options>
        </app-rx-search-field>
```

```js
this.providerSchoolSearchCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        mergeMap(search => of(search).pipe(
          delay(500)
        ))
      ).subscribe({
      next: value => {
        this.store.dispatch(new GetSchoolRequest({isRequesting: true, searchPhrase: value}));
      }
    });
```

```js
public onOptionSelected = (event: any) => {
    console.log(event);
// This is to set the value for the input field
    this.providerSchoolSearchCtrl.setValue(event.option['school.name']);
    this.providerEducation.controls['school'].setValue(event.option['school.name'], {emitEvent: false});
  }
```

Comment: Please have two input fields, one is to search and another one is to bind the selected option. once the user selected the option, hide the search input field and show another input field where you bind the value.

Comment: As I'm developing a library so this implementation will be not a good approach. Angular Material doesn't do so.

Comment: So, you are going to release an npm?

Comment: Yes, right.. thats the goal of the entire project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this option, when sets the value to the control. The `setValue` method has a second parameter by which we can control whether we should emit event or not.

```
 this.providerSchoolSearchCtrl.setValue(event.option['school.name'], {emitEvent: false});
```

Have a look at the angular docs: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setValue

Comment: I missed to include that in that line, but in the below line I added that arg. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Angular gives you the power that, when you change value of any formControl programatically, it's upto you that do you want to fire a "valueChanges" event.

What you need to do is : 
Change this `this.providerSchoolSearchCtrl.setValue(event.option['school.name']);`

To this
`this.providerSchoolSearchCtrl.setValue(event.option['school.name'],{emitEvent:false});`
And then valueChanges will not emit an event.

This also means that the statusChanges will not be fired (if you are using that at all).

Please mark this answer as resolved if this resolved your issue. :)

More info on the Angular Repo
[Official Angular Repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.2.11/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1028-L1064)